# How to solve the following error for loading data

Tags: teradata, loading

Below is my code for creating and loading data with fastload onto teradata database.

```
CREATE TABLE MARK,FALLBACK
(
  A INTEGER NOT NULL,
  B INTEGER NOT NULL,
  C DATE,
  D INTEGER NOT NULL,
  E DECIMAL(10,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (D) 
) PRIMARY INDEX(A,B);
```

While processing the fastload script, it gives an error of

```
 RDBMS error 3621: Cannot load table MARK
 unless secondary indexes and join indexes are removed
```

How should I solve this kind of problem?

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You can either remove the indexes, load your data, and recreate the indexes, or probably a better option is to fload into a staging table, and then insert into your final table.

Comment: The *Primary Key* constraint is implemented as *Unique Secondary Index*, FastLoad/TPT Load doesn't support Secondary Indexes.